# Oracle 12.2 - how to force APEX installation during database install?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

Now that, [since 12.2, Oracle no longer install APEX by default](https://oracle-base.com/blog/2017/03/10/oracle-database-12c-release-2-12-2-default-apex-installation-gone/), is there a way to force the APEX installation during installation of the database? It's quite a pain having to manually re-install APEX after each 12c install.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way you can accomplish this is by creating your own Database Template which includes APEX. Mike Dietrich has an excellent blog post about database templates [here](https://mikedietrichde.com/2017/07/12/use-your-own-templates-in-dbca-to-create-databases/).

Keep in mind, that will install the version of APEX that is in the database home, which may not always be the latest version of APEX.

Whatever you do, I advise against installing APEX common (in CDB$ROOT), and only install it locally in a PDB.